# Add calendar datepicker with Jquery on dynamic table

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a Jquery calendar picker to a text box at the time of creation, but I cant find how.

When I press a button, it will create a table, the element I want to attach the Jquery calendar picker is:

```
var txtDate = createTextInput(i, "txtDate", 8, 10);
txtDate.className  = "datepicker";
this.newcells[i].appendChild(txtDate);
```

I tried adding at the end :

```
txtDate.datepicker();
```

But does not work. Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Note: CreateTextInput is:

```
function createTextInput(i, strName, size, maxLength) {
    var input = document.createElement('<input>');
    input.type = "text";
    input.name = strName;
    input.id = strName + i;
    input.size = size;
    input.maxLength = maxLength;

    return input;
}
```

Comment: Thank to @Matti, @Alexander and @Rahul, but none of your answer have solve my problem so far.
I do not know if where I am placing that line its not the right place.
Could anybody tell me where shoul I put $(txtDate).datepicker(); ?
I am adding it after this.newcells[i].appendChild(txtDate).
Thanks.

Comment: If txtDate is the id of your textbox then you have to code like this `$("#txtDate").datepicker();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$("#txtDate").datepicker();
```

instead of

```
txtDate.datepicker();
```

You can create an element using jQuery with ease. Something like

```
$("<input type='text' />").attr("id", '').appendTo("yourelement");
```

You can rewrite the createtextinput function like this in jQuery

```
function createTextInput(i, strName, size, maxLength) {
    return $("<input />".attr({
        type: 'text',
        name: strName,
        id: strName + i,
        size: size,
        maxLength: maxLength
    });    
}
```

If you are returning the jQuery object then you can directly call datepicker(), like

```
txtDate.datepicker();
```

Comment: Would that pick the name or the id?, as the element has an id and a different name than the id. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to select using name then you can write `$("input[name=inputname]")`

Comment: Thank you rahul, this really helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

If `createTextInput` is returning a plain DOM node instead of a jQuery object, you need to use `$()` on the result.

```
$(txtDate).datepicker();
```

Comment: This didn't work, I dont get any error but it does not add it.
Is there any other information that may help you to help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(txtDate).datepicker();
```